# searching 2 criteria in another worksheet and returning cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to match name and date from one sheet to another and return corresponding cell value from that sheet to fill a column.

Active sheet to be filled has 24000 rows and sheet with data to be matched and copied over has 14645. Columns are name, date, break time in each (names in one are a shorter string ID, hence the use of `InStr` (e.g. "Willia" and "WilliamsA").

My code steps through about 200 rows and ends.  Not sure if it's a crash or a bug. Any help appreciated.

```
Sub matchnamedate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = false

Dim i As Integer
Dim rcell As Range
Dim rrng As Range

Set rrng = Range("T2:T24000")
Range("t2").Activate

For Each rcell In rrng

For i = 2 To 14645

If InStr(1, Worksheets("Max Breaks by Day").Cells(i, 1).Text, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Text) And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Worksheets("Max Breaks by Day").Cells(i, 2) Then


ActiveCell.Value = Worksheets("Max Breaks by Day").Cells(i, 3).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate


End If
Next i

Next rcell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You never use `rcell`, so effectively your outer loop could simply be a `For j = 1 To 23999` (or any large number).  Your main issue is that, in your inner loop, you only move to the next cell to be compared *if the previous one has been matched*, although sometimes you do that more than once for each iteration of the outer loop.  If you don't actually match a cell, then for the remaining iterations of the outer loop you are just constantly trying to match the cell that didn't match - a pointless exercise.

I believe the following will achieve what you are trying to do:

```
Sub matchnamedate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rcell As Range
    Dim rrng As Range

    Set rrng = Range("T2:T24000")

    For Each rcell In rrng

        For i = 2 To 14645
            If InStr(1, Worksheets("Max Breaks by Day").Cells(i, 1).Text, rcell.Offset(0, -2).Text) > 0 And _
               Worksheets("Max Breaks by Day").Cells(i, 2) = rcell.Offset(0, -1).Value Then

                rcell.Value = Worksheets("Max Breaks by Day").Cells(i, 3).Value
                'Exit if a match has been found
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

    Next rcell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the great catch. This seemed to avoid one loop problem.  Now it runs, but I've figured out that when it gets to a name and date in active sheet that is not a match in the Max Breaks Sheet, it still gets stuck.  Not sure why when there's no match, it doesn't move on to the next rcell?

Comment: @NickR Actually, I have just noticed one thing - your `InStr(...)` was missing the `> 0` that should have come after it, but that's just poor coding - the fact that the `Worksheets("Max Breaks by Day").Cells(i, 2) = rcell.Offset(0, -1).Value` test for equality is higher in the expression evaluation hierarchy than the "numeric And" means the statement should still process correctly (e.g. using `5 > 0 And 1 = 1` is `True And True` is `True`, but your code is `5 And 1 = 1` which is `5 And -1` which is `5` which would still be treated as `True`)